# Saving file with angular-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use `angular-file-upload` in my application in order to save a file.

I have the next code:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(valid, commit, file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
        url: '/tmp',
        data: {file: file, username: $scope.username},
    });
    file.upload.then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, function(env){
        console.log(env);
    })
```

The application is running on my machine, and I want that the file will save on the `/tmp` folder.  The problem is that when I write `tmp`, it search the address `/tmp`, and not the location `/tmp`. How can I save the file without call to API?

Answer (score 0):

You can't save files on server from client side without going though some kind of backend.

Angular file uploader sends a HTTP request to "url", in this case it tries to send to /tmp which most likely don't point to anything

Answer (score 0):

In this case the client is trying to find that url in the server, which is not your case, you may need to develop a backend part too.

For testing purposes, remember you can use $httpbackend to [fake HTTP backend implementation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)